# Load bootstrap JS with esbuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, es6-modules, esbuild

I'm trying to import the [bootstrap JS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/v4.1.3/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js) in my esbuild build:

```js
// index.js
import 'jquery-import'
import 'bootstrap'

// jquery-import.js
import jquery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = window.$ = jquery;
```

The build target is `esm`. The problem is that the following bootstrap code is run:

```js
factory(exports, require('jquery'), require('popper.js'));
```

This does not use my global `window.jQuery` but rather requires its own, which means that my global `window.$.fn` doesn't include the Bootstrap extensions. Also, I think that this makes jQuery load twice.

Is there a way of fixing this without adapting the bootstrap source code?

---

A little more background on this:

The bootstrap source code begins with the following statements (lightly adapted for better readability):

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    // Option 1: The route taken by esbuild
    factory(exports, require('jquery'), require('popper.js'));
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // Option 2
    define(['exports', 'jquery', 'popper.js'], factory);
  } else {
    // Option 2
    (global = global || self, factory(global.bootstrap = {}, global.jQuery, global.Popper));
  }
}(this, function (exports, $, Popper) { 'use strict';
```

I have tried commenting out individual options, and neither 1, 2 or 3 work by just taking the already globally defined `window.jQuery`.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working, is for some reason your esbuild is trying to import a UMD file (typically used for old Node and browser hybrid code).

Having looked at bootstrap's package.json, it seems that `"module": "dist/js/bootstrap.js"`, which exports bootstrap as modules, which is probably what esbuild should be referencing.

So to fix this without fixing the esbuild config, I'd conjecture you could try:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
```

...or to fix it with esbuild config, add this:

```js
const buildOpts = {
  mainFields: ['module', 'main'],
}
```

This setting tells the bundler to prioritises module, then main entrypoints.

Normally this is module before main, but it may be the other way round because you set [platform](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#platform) to "node".